# Aligning values with timestamps to a timeline

Tags: gnuplot

I want to visualize data given at certain timestamps from multiple sources along a timeline. For example, with the follwing to input files with column 1 being the timestamp and column 2 the data:

O1.dat:

```
100 5
300 10
```

O2.dat:

```
200 7
400 3
```

Along with that the average of all values is sampled at certain intervals:

Avg.dat:

```
250 6.5
500 6.25
```

I would like to plot all values in a table-like manner so it looks something like this, with the values aligned to the time on the top:

[image]

My real data reaches timestamps of up to 10000, so something dynamic would be nice.

So far I only plotted simple box or line plots, so I'm not sure how to go about this one.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

This is what it looks like so far with adjustments made to the accepted answer:

[image]

There is still some overlapping, but that is simply because of the data being too close to each other. The script used for this:

```
#set term pdf
#set term pdf size 8, 5
#set output 'out.pdf'
set term png
set term png size 1200, 700
set output 'out.png'

set termoption font ",20"
set label 'Time (ms)' at graph 0, graph 1 offset -0.75, char 1 right
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
set ytics scale 0
set x2tics () scale 0
set yrange [0:5.5]
set x2range[0:10000]
set lmargin 9

set arrow from graph -0.15, graph 1 to graph 1.1, graph 1 nohead
set arrow from graph -0.01, graph 1.2 to graph -0.01, graph -0.2 nohead
set arrow from graph -0.15, first 0.3 to graph 1.1, first 0.3 nohead

set style data labels
plot for [i=0:9] 'desc'.i.'.txt' using 1:(5-0.5*i):(sprintf('%d', $2)):ytic('Object '.i) axes x2y1, \
     'Avg.dat' using 1:(0):(sprintf('%d', $2)):ytic('Avg') axes x2y1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional, simple part is plotting of the actual data. For this you can use the `labels` plotting style. A very simple example would be:

```
set xtics (0)
set xrange [0:*]
set offsets graph 0, graph 0.2, graph 0.2, graph 0.2
set style data labels
unset key
plot 'O1.dat' using 1:(5):(gprintf('%g', $2)):ytic('O1'),\
     'O2.dat' using 1:(4):(gprintf('%g', $2)):ytic('O2'),\
     'Avg.dat' using 1:(3):(gprintf('%g', $2)):ytic('Avg'):xtic(1)
```

That simply plots the values from your data files as labels at the x-positions given in the first columns. The y-positions are set as fixed numbers:

[image]

In order to move the xtick labels to the top and have some table-like lines you need a bit more tweaking:

```
reset

set termoption font ",20"
set label 'Object' at graph 0, graph 1 offset -1, char 1 right
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
set ytics scale 0
set x2tics () scale 0 format "%g"
set yrange [2:5.5]
set x2range[0:*]
set lmargin 8

set arrow from graph -0.15, graph 1 to graph 1.1, graph 1 nohead
set arrow from graph 0, graph 1.2 to graph 0, graph 0 nohead
set arrow from graph -0.15, first 3.25 to graph 1.1, first 3.25 nohead

set style data labels
plot 'O1.dat' using 1:(5):(sprintf('%d', $2)):ytic('O1') axes x2y1,\
     'O2.dat' using 1:(4):(sprintf('%d', $2)):ytic('O2') axes x2y1,\
     'Avg.dat' using 1:(2.5):(gprintf('%g', $2)):ytic('Avg'):x2tic(1) axes x2y1
```

Such a table layout isn't a typical task, so you must adapt several settings to your final result. Main impact comes from canvas size, font and, font size.

[image]

If you have more than those two files you could of course also iterate over a file list.

Comment: This was spot-on, thank you very much. I edited my question with the current result. There's still some adjusting to do, but looks pretty good.